# Stuck on Plugins Check

Tags: moodle

I tried to install without realising an older plugin than what was already installed. It errored with the install however now I cant get past the check plugins screen to fix my issue.

[image: Main page]

Reload just reloads the page, update does nothing. If I click Upgrade I get this:

[image: Error page]

I cant do anything else. If I try to reload Moodle with just http://moodle (Internal URL) I get redirected straight back to this page. If I clear my cookies I get taken to the login page, but after logging in it is straight back to the "Plugins Check" page again.

Comment: This question require example texts, images are lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have administrative access to the server running Moodle?

You should be able to download the version of the plugin you need and unzip it directly into Moodle's directory structure, and then log back in to the Web UI.

In my moodle installation, this is here:
/var/www/html/moodle/course/format/singleactivity

You should be able to get the correct files from the installation package you used. Just make a backup of the existing folder in your Moodle environment, move it to a safe location, and drop the complete folder for the new version in its place. Then reload the web client.